# How to deal with missing data for only some categories

Tags: categorical-data, data-imputation

Or in other words, data for category A is irrelevant for category B. So it is not present, how can imputing missing data distort/effect learning models broadly. 
I can't find any logic how to deal with this relative data. So I am sorry that I don't show any effort.

In the following example, geographical zone is only present for Gaz entries.

Data sample:

[image]

Comment: Depends on what's your task. What do you want to do with the data? Add more info in the question!

Comment: show cross-table produit and zone. because your problem is not clear yet.

Answer (score 7):

There are three *types* of missing data: [Missing Completely At Random (MCAR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data#Missing_completely_at_random), **[Missing At Random (MAR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data#Missing_at_random)** and [Missing Not At Random (MNAR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data#Missing_not_at_random).

Your case is the second, where according to wikipedia it:

> occurs when the missingness is not random, but where missingness can be fully accounted for by variables where there is complete information

This means that the presence or not of entries in `zone` can be derived from the column `Produit`.

Because the values aren't missing completely at random, normal imputation techniques (e.g. fill with the most common value) **shouldn't be applied**. Instead I'd recommend treating the missing values as **their own category**. Just create a category (let's say `not available`) and fill the missing with this value. From a data science view this makes more sense.

Comment: Missing Not At Random (MNAR) really makes sense, but in this specific case, I'm afraid making "not available" adds information, which distort real life state that learning data is trying to represent, because of the following: `Zone` is saying something about `Produit`, when it's `gaz`, but saying nothing about it when it's `elec`. Saying  `not available` creates another categorical value that says something, in the same level of importance of other values. So I am not fully agreeing on how to deal with Missing Not At Random (MNAR) in this case

Comment: Actually, I think the variable is MAR (I made a typo in the post). The thing about imputing is that you don't do it to elevate the representation of your data, but to **avoid throwing those samples** (which would be necessary if you didn't impute them).  It's a *lesser of two evils* type of thing. And I think that since the missing data has a pattern you can use this to your advantage.